# Grunt concat includes a file that it should ignore; why is it ignoring Gruntfile.js?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a Grunt task to concat 3x JS files into a single `plugins.js` file. I now no longer require one of the files (let's call it `unrequired.js`), so I've removed it from the list of source files in `Gruntfile.js`. However, whenever I run `grunt concat`, the output file *still* contains `unrequired.js`. The only way around it is to trash `unrequired.js` and then run the task again. Is there some kind of caching feature at play here? Does the concat task ignore changes being made to `Gruntfile`? What am I missing?

Comment: can you share the relevant parts of your grunt file? (which grunt plugin it is, any custom task function, etc)

Comment: I'm going to try and set up a minimal test case to see if I can get reproduce this problem constantly. I was just hoping someone might point me towards something obvious that I've overlooked!

Comment: Are you creating the file list for concat with usemin-prepare?